# How to sort the Recyclerview from last ID to first ID?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm asking for help on sorting the Recyclerview from the last id to the first id.

I want to show up in recyclerview, when I add a row in the database.

How to display the last row in the database as the first card in the list?

this is my php code:

```
<?php 
    //Creating a connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("--","---","----","-----");

        /* change character set to utf8 */
    $con->set_charset("utf8");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    /*Get the id of the last visible item in the RecyclerView from the request and store it in a variable. For            the first request id will be zero.*/  
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    $sql= "Select * from movies_table where id between ($id+1) and ($id+10)";

    $result = mysqli_query($con ,$sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $array[] = $row;

    }
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

    mysqli_free_result($result);

    mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

and this my recyclerview class:

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = ThreeFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<Movie> movies;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayout;
    private MoviesAdapter adapter;


    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        movies = new ArrayList<>();
        getMoviesFromDB(0);

        gridLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayout);

        adapter = new MoviesAdapter(getActivity(), movies);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                if (gridLayout.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == movies.size() - 1) {
                    getMoviesFromDB(movies.get(movies.size() - 1).getId());
                }

            }
        });
        return view;
    }




    private void getMoviesFromDB(int id) {

        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {



            ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                //this method will be running on UI thread
                pdLoading.setMessage("\tدر حال بارگذاری...");
                pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
                pdLoading.show();

            }


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... movieIds) {

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://astaneapp.ir/wp-php/movies.php?id=" + movieIds[0])
                        .build();
                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        Movie movie = new Movie(object.getInt("id"), object.getString("movie_name"),
                                object.getString("movie_image"), object.getString("movie_genre") , object.getString("movie_discription") , object.getString("movie_lat"), object.getString("movie_lon") , object.getString("movie_marker"));

                        ThreeFragment.this.movies.add(movie);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pdLoading.dismiss();
            }
        };

        asyncTask.execute(id);
    }
}
```

Do I need to send the adapter class codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

    Collections.sort(ThreeFragment.this.movies, new Comparator<Movie>() {
        public int compare(Movie o1, Movie o2) {
            Integer firstItem = o1.getId();
            Integer secondItem = o2.getId();
            return secondItem.compareTo(firstItem);
        }
    });

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    pdLoading.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i get this error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Long

Comment: thank you, this code worrked too for me, the only problem is that I want the data to be loaded 10 to 10. Can you help me in this case too? I post new modified codes

Comment: @FarshadAsgharzadeh *"this code worrked too for me"* is what you stated. If this solved the original question, it should be accepted as the correct answer. If you have another question regarding new code, then you need to ask a new question and not append to another possible problem after you asked.

Comment: @fred-ii It works, but incompletely! Some other parts work out! I want to be completely solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can order your data in the server side (php) by DESC order by id

```
$sql= "Select * from movies_table where id between ($id+1) and ($id+10) ORDER BY 'id' DESC";
```

or You Can reorder the array you get from the server:

```
   for(int i=(YourArrayData.size()-1);i>=0;i--)
   {
    newArrayList.add(YourArrayData.get(i));
   }

add your newArrayList to adapter
```

Comment: thanks for answer , I tried the code and did not make any changes.

Comment: @FarshadAsgharzadeh what is the result you get ?

Comment: The list is displayed, like before, from old to new

Comment: in php everyting is reverse! thanks! but in java code "size" code is displayed as red color! Can you example in my code?

Comment: I apologize that I replied late, the database data was reversed, and I got to what I wanted, the only problem is that I want the data to be loaded 10 to 10. Can you help me in this case too? I post new modified codes